# What camera and accessories do I need for taking photos of paintings made with acrylics?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, digital-vs-film, artwork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best practices for taking pictures of a canvas?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/what-are-the-best-practices-for-taking-pictures-of-a-canvas)

I currently have a 2 year old digital camera and am looking into taking professional photos of my artwork, mainly acrylic paintings. I was wondering, starting out, what is the best kind of camera and accessories that are required and which items might be a good idea to have. Would any digital camera work, or would a film camera be better?

I realize that if you take a picture with a film camera you can better guarantee the number of prints made; yet I want a digital copy of the final print (to do different things with) so that is not brought into account.

Comment: Also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15612/how-do-i-best-take-pictures-of-paintings may help.

Comment: Also useful to take a look at http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/how-do-you-photograph-artwork-in-a-glass-picture-frame and http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/14788/1359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital is better than film:

1. easier
2. film processing requires a pro lab.
3. if using film, you should shoot on transparency which requires an accuracy of 1/3 of a stop.

Raw files have +/- 1 stop flexibility.
Raw files have colour temp flexibility.
Digital is more sensitive to subtle variations in tone ~ therefore
You should mix daylight and flash lighting balanced across the exposure area.
That's the best solution for paintings.

Comment: Any specific kind brand of digital camera? Can you mention some specification for the camera that are required and/or nice to have?